# How to make an Environment Variable available to Systemd Services

Tags: linux, environment-variables, systemd, centos-7

I have a script in `/etc/profile.d/setenv.sh` which sets the value for `JAVA_HOME` so that `$JAVA_HOME` will be available system-wide:

```
# echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74" > /etc/profile.d/setenv.sh
```

When I login to shell I can write `echo $JAVA_HOME` and I see the path properly, but the service that is started with Systemd does not see that variable.

How can I have that environment variable visible to Systemd services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page for `systemd-system.conf`

This is refering to the file located at `/etc/systemd/system.conf` on my box.  It is probably where yours is too

You can put some options in there.  The one you want would look something like

`DefaultEnvironment="VAR1=word1 word2" VAR2=word3 "VAR3=word 5 6"`

There is a commented out blank prototype in the `system.conf` installed on my system.  Change that to add your environment defintiton